# Is there any browsers that sends multipart/form-data sub-parts?

Tags: c++, post, webserver, multipartform-data

I am writing a [webserver](http://snapwebsites.org/) in C++.  I am looking at the `POST` documentation on w3:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

I see that a `POST` is supposed to support the full multi-parts scheme: parts and sub-parts (and obviously, sub-sub-parts...) just like for email attachments.

Is there any browser and/or tool that do that on a normal basis? In other words, is it really important for a server to support parts and sub-parts?

The obvious problem with that is the fact that it could mean that two files are uploaded under the same name. That's quite a problem if you ask me. Also, from what I can see in PHP it is not supported at all in that realm. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Ah! I guess I should have searched a little more and to tell you the truth I had not thought of looking at HTML5 for the answer.

The following paragraph actually includes the answer:

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#multipart-form-data

> Note: In particular, this means that multiple files submitted as
>   part of a single  element will
>   result in each file having its own field; the "sets of
>   files" feature ("multipart/mixed") of RFC 2388 is not used.

So it is clear that sub-parts (multipart/mixed) are not to be supported.

Comment: CURL uses multipart for sending files by default I believe.  If you run the command line version of curl to post multiple files you can see an example.  http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html  Section 4.3.  There are ways to format the request where each part is named.  I've done this before but I think it was more a feature of MIME.

Comment: I tested and could not generate anything wrong (i.e. none of the HTTP data included sub-parts.) I used the --form option as mentioned in Section 4.3. I tried with two files with the same name and two files with the same field name and I just receive two separate files as expected.